# Правки по переводу

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

[Flag](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/40265050?qt=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Две строки:
3258 Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention

*Отметьте комментарий тревогой, чтобы обозначить серьезную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора*

3425 flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention

*отметьте тревогой сообщение с целью обозначить серьезную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора*

Вторая строка (3425) содержит `с целью`, которое "ломает" литературность фразы. Можно заменить либо на "чтобы", как в первом случае, либо на "если хотите": `отметьте тревогой сообщение, если хотите обозначить серьезную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора` (и, конечно же, желательно чтобы обе строки использовали один и тот же вариант).

---

[put on hold](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/40265896?q=**put%20on%20hold**)

Строки 4241 и 4253. Довольно странно читать что-нибудь вроде `заморожен по причине всеобъемлющий пользователем N`. Возможно, что лучше было бы `заморожен (причина: всеобъемлющий) пользователем N`. Такой шаблон получается достаточно универсальным и имеет нормальную читаемость.

`**заморожен** (причина: $closeReason$) $onDate$`

`**заморожен** (причина: $closeReason$) пользователем $userCommas$ $onDate$`

Comment: Можно так: `**заморожен** пользователем $userCommas$ $onDate$ по причине: $closeReason$`. А то предложение разрывается.

Comment: Не вижу проблем с разрывом, так как статус и причина представляют всю основную информацию, которую сразу же получает читатель. А список проголосовавших и дата - это уже второстепенная информация. Если пользователь видит, что начался список имён, то скорее всего, вряд ли он будет их дальше внимательно читать, поэтому я бы не переносил причину в конец предложения.

Comment: Кроме того, само "по причине" применяется в формах вроде "по причине отсутствия", "по причине неспособности" и т.п. А к "не по теме", "всеобъемлющий" и т.п., больше подходит "причина".

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но неужели никому не режет слух оборот "Отметьте комментарий тревогой"? Это ужасное словосочетание, которое не встречается нигде, кроме SO. Т.к. это всплывающая подсказка к кнопке "тревога", ее можно сформулировать иначе: "Нажмите "тревога", чтобы..." или просто "отметьте это сообщение, чтобы.." и "отметьте этот комментарий, чтобы..."

Comment: Режет. Есть множество вещей, которые можно сделать лучше.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev: очень режет. Мне вообще все эти тревоги режут слух.

Comment: По поводу «тревоги», мы долго обсуждали, но не смогли найти более хороший перевод, который бы ложился на _все_ случаи использования. Если у кого есть хорошие идеи — думаю, все с удовольствием согласятся на замену.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: вот тут приведены варианты перевода *flag* и связанных с ним выражений: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467/178576