# 33 активности, новая строка!

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не знаю, как лучше оформлять - как новый вопрос, как ответ в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/118/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83), или просто добавлять в тело предыдущего вопроса... (надеюсь, что кто-то подскажет)

Если в профиле нажать `all actions`, то выводится список с заголовком. например таким: `33 активности`. "Активность" не применяется во множественном числе. Предлагаю `активности` поменять хотя бы на `события` (конечно же, с учётом склонений). Более правильно было бы переводить `actions` как `действия`, но для некоторых видов `actions` больше подходит `событие`, а не `действие` (например, `присуждено`), так как действие подразумевает то, что делает пользователь. При этом, непосредственно пункт меню `all actions` вполне может быть `вся активность`.

Comment: Эээ... А где вы это нашли? В моём профиле я вижу лишь «все действия». Или вопрос уже устарел?

Comment: @VladD Сообщение от 7 апреля, уже исправили давно, как понимаю

Comment: Понял. Стукнул в чат модераторам, пусть поставят метку [tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 3):

Action это именно действие. Так что я за вариант

> 31 действие
>   33 действия
>   35 действий
>   все действия

Получить знак - тоже действие.